# How to access sites and api with different domain from mac

Tags: browser, server, dns, ip, probe

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, so please do not mind if the wording sounds a bit unusual. I am trying to search this API (api.quotable.io/random) but it's throwing the following error:

```
This site can’t be reached
api.quotable.io’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Some specific information about the domain of this API can be found [here](https://www.whois.com/whois/quotable.io)

The confusing part is that it works perfectly when searched from a Windows machine, but not from mac.

I have tried the following steps, but so far unsuccessful:

1. Changing DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
2. Clearing browsing data and cache
3. Clearing DNS cache

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question Iraj. I have only used Stackoverflow for either answering or looking for answers. I never asked any questions. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi! The API is working now. Perhaps it was recovered by the domain registrar. But thanks if you were attempting to check it out.